# How to prevent Outlook reminder dialog when querying Exchange Web Services?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a Delphi application in which I'm retrieving appointment data from Exchange Web Services with (only) SOAP calls.
This is Exchange 2010 on a separate server.
The virtual machine in which I'm working has a copy of Outlook 2003 connected to Exchange.
Outlook is not running, neither is there an outlook.exe in the task list.

What surprises me:
When I query EWS for appointment details (a GetItem SOAP request that retrieves the body text and some other data) an Outlook dialog pops up if there are outstanding reminders.

Can this be prevented?

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm!

In the Delphi application I was using a Developer Express scheduler component and the warning came from there, not from Outlook.

Sorry ;-)